# Why showing pear and phpunit is not installed in xampp on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, php, xampp, pear, phpunit

I have installed xampp 1.8 on my ubuntu 12.04. In /opt/lampp/lib/php/PEAR I can see there are two directory named PEAR and PHPUnit.

But when I run pear -V or phpunit from terminal it gives the below messages:

> The program 'pear' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
>   sudo apt-get install php-pear

and

> The program 'phpunit' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
>   sudo apt-get install phpunit

Why these messages are showing ? Do I need to install pear and phpunit again. If so how to do this as I still have PEAR and PHPUnit directory /opt/lampp/lib/php/

Comment: Is there anyone who have faced this type of problem

Comment: Should I ask this in stackoverflow ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the xampp bin/ directory to your `$PATH` variable; otherwise the executables cannot be found.

This could be done by e.g.

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/lib/php/bin
```

in your `.bashrc`, so it gets automatically executed whenever you open a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and the steps I followed to resolve it were as follows:

- I had PHP installed separate to XAMPP from a previous attempt so I removed it first using `sudo apt-get -y purge php.*` to ensure that I was using the XAMPP PHP setup (as this was causing some confusion!)
- Edit the .bashrc file in the following location: `/home/<your user>/.bashrc`
- Add at the bottom of the page the path to the /bin folder in XAMPP - in my case this was `PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin`

After I followed these steps, closed down my Konsole window and re-opened then I could run the PHP script I was trying to use.